# Ssh X11 forwarding messes up with default shell

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, sh, x11-forwarding

I have a `bash` specific code  in my bash profile:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "SHELL: $SHELL"
function printfiles() {
  while IFS='' read -r _file || [[ -n "$_file" ]]; do
    echo "file: ${_file}"
  done < <(ls)
} && export -f printfiles
```

The `< <(FUNCTION)` is `bash` specific syntax, unsupported by `sh`.  When I log in to a remote machine with ssh:

```
$ ssh my.remote
me@xxx.xx.xxx.xx's password: 
Last login: Fri Nov 17 11:27:39 2017 from yyy.yy.yy.yy
sourcing /home/me/.bash_profile
SHELL: /bin/bash
```

It works fine. Now I want to log in again but forwarding my `X11`:

```
$ ssh -X my.remote
me@xxx.xx.xxx.xx's password: 
sh: printfiles: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
                                                              sh: printfiles: line 2: ` done < <(ls)'
                                                                                                     sh: error importing function definition for `printfiles'
               sh: printfiles: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
                                                                             sh: printfiles: line 2: ` done < <(ls)'
                                                                                                                    sh: error importing function definition for `printfiles'
                              sh: printfiles: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
                                                                                            sh: printfiles: line 2: ` done < <(ls)'
                                                                                                                                   sh: error importing function definition for `printfiles'
                                             sh: printfiles: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
                                                                                                           sh: printfiles: line 2: ` done < <(ls)'
    sh: error importing function definition for `printfiles'
                                                            Last login: Fri Nov 17 11:28:51 2017 from yyy.yy.yy.yy
sourcing /home/me/.bash_profile
SHELL: /bin/bash
```

I have no clue what is happening, it seems that when I do the X11 forwarding somehow the `sh` shell is used over `bash`. Why so, how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If I see inconsistencies between -X and -x logins, I suspect:

1. Differences among .bash_profile/.profile and .bashrc - see excellent discussion at https://serverfault.com/a/261807/116193
2. Interaction of my local environment with the remote - I debug this by stripping out controlling the local environment, such as with `env -i ssh ...`

Also: generally, I like to use -x to troubleshoot many of these types of things.  You may be able to configure the Shell on the server side to enable the trace (-x) on login.

If I think of others, I'll update.